# Yet another Python text editor

Tags: python

Here's what I managed to do. It is rather limited and I had to get help from the internet in some places.

Can you review it, give me some tips on making the code better, cleaner, faster etc.?

**editor.py**

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter.messagebox
import os

try:
    import config
    import menu
    import syntaxhl
    import findtool

except ImportError as e:
    import sys
    sys.exit("Import error.\nRaw: {}".format(e))

class Editor(object):

    def editor(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        self.config = config.config()
        self.syntaxcolor = config.syntaxHighligh()

        self.root.wm_title(self.config.editor_title)
        self.root.attributes("-alpha", self.config.transparency)

        # Scrollbar
        self.scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(self.root)
        self.scrollbar.pack(side = tkinter.RIGHT, fill = tkinter.Y)

        # Editor.
        self.editor_space = tkinter.Text(self.root)
        self.editor_space.config(undo = self.config.undo, width = self.config.width,
                                 height = self.config.height, fg = self.config.foreground,
                                 bg = self.config.background, insertbackground = self.config.cursorColor,
                                 yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set,
                                 font = (self.config.font, self.config.font_size))

        self.editor_space.pack(fill = tkinter.X)
        self.scrollbar.config(command = self.editor_space.yview)

        # Find tool
        find = findtool.Find(self.editor_space)

        # Menu.
        # Note: The order of the instances is the order in witch the menus will appear.
        self.mn = tkinter.Menu(self.root)
        self.filemenu = menu.FileMenu(self.mn, self.openFile,
                                      self.saveFile, self.destroy,
                                      self.root)

        self.toolmenu = menu.ToolsMenu(self.mn, self.clear,
                                       self.syntaxHighlight,
                                       find.find)

        self.prefmenu = menu.Settings(self.mn, self.openConfigFile)
        self.helpmenu = menu.HelpMenu(self.mn, self.about)

        # Close event.
        if self.config.askokcancel:
            self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.destroy)

        self.root.config(menu = self.mn)

        self.root.mainloop()

    def openConfigFile(self):
        try:
            with open("config.py") as file:
                for line in file.readlines():
                    self.editor_space.insert(tkinter.END, line)

        except IOError as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Couldn't open file.")

        except Exception as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error.\n{}".format(repr(e)))

    def destroy(self):
        ako = tkinter.messagebox.askokcancel("Quit", "Are you sure you want to exit?")
        if ako:
            self.root.quit()

    def clear(self):
        self.editor_space.delete("1.0", tkinter.END)

    def saveFile(self):
        path = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension = self.config.defext)
        filename = os.path.basename(path)

        try:
            with open(filename, "w") as wf:
                wf.write(self.editor_space.get("0.0", tkinter.END))

            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(None, "File saved.")

        except IOError as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Couldn't open file.")

        except Exception as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error.\n{}".format(repr(e)))

    def openFile(self):
        self.clear()
        file = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile()
        try:
            for line in file.readlines():
                self.editor_space.insert(tkinter.END, line)

            self.syntaxHighlight()

        except IOError as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Couldn't open file.")

        except Exception as e:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror("Error", "Error.\n{}".format(repr(e)))

    def syntaxHighlight(self):
        for keyw, color in getattr(self.syntaxcolor, "colors").items():
            syntaxhl.highlight(self.editor_space, keyw, color)

    def about(self):
        pass
```

**config.py**

```
class config(object):
    editor_title = "TEdit"
    undo = 1 # 1 - Enable

    # The default extension used when saving a file.
    defext = ".txt"

    # Size of the editor window.
    width = 150
    height = 50

    askokcancel = False
    matchColor = "blue"

    # Theme
    transparency = 1
    background = "black"
    foreground = "white"
    font = "Arial"
    font_size = 18
    cursorColor = "green"

class syntaxHighligh(object):
    colors = {"import" : "red",
              "def" : "red",
              "format" : "red",
              "if" : "red",
              "class" : "red",
              "else" : "red",
              "elif" : "red",
              "=" : "red",
              "try" : "red",
              "except" : "red",
              "finally" : "red",
              "yield" : "red",
              "return" : "red",
              "not" : "red",
              "pass" : "red",
              "for": "red",
              "pass": "red",
              "in" : "red",
              "print" : "red",
              "lambda" : "red",
              }
```

**findtool.py**

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk
import config

class Find(object):

    def __init__(self, es):
        self.editor_space = es
        self.config = config.config()

    def find(self):
        # Find window and stuff.
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        tkinter.Label(root, text = "Seach for: ").grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        input_ = tkinter.ttk.Entry(root, width = 20)
        input_.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.editor_space.tag_configure("search", background = self.config.matchColor)

        # Search button.
        tkinter.ttk.Button(root, text = "Search", command=lambda: self.search_editor_space(input_.get())).grid(row = 2, column = 1,
                                                                                                           columnspan = 2)

        # On close.
        root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.destroy_find_window(root))


    def destroy_find_window(self, root):
        self.editor_space.tag_remove("found", "1.0", tkinter.END)
        root.destroy()

    def search_editor_space(self, searchfor):
        # Actual search.
        # Got from(with small modifications): http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/GUI-Tk/SearchstringinText.html
        # Thanks.

        self.editor_space.tag_config("found", foreground = self.config.matchColor)
        countVar = tkinter.IntVar()

        item = "1.0"

        while True:
            item = self.editor_space.search(searchfor, item, tkinter.END, count = countVar)

            if not item:
                break

            lastindex = "{} + {}c".format(item, countVar.get())

            self.editor_space.tag_add("found", item, lastindex)

            item = lastindex
```

**menu.py**

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.ttk

class FileMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, menubar, openFunc, saveFunc, closeFunc, root):
        self.of = openFunc
        self.sf = saveFunc
        self.cf = closeFunc

        self.menu = tkinter.Menu(menubar)

        filemenu = tkinter.Menu(self.menu)
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = self.of)
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Save", command = self.sf)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label = "Exit", command = self.cf)

        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = filemenu)

class HelpMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, menubar, aboutFunc):
        self.helpmenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar)

        self.helpmenu.add_command(label = "About", command = aboutFunc)

        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Help", menu = self.helpmenu)

class ToolsMenu(object):

    def __init__(self, menubar, clearFunc, syntaxHighL, find):
        self.cf = clearFunc
        self.fd = find
        self.sh = syntaxHighL
        self.toolsmenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar)

        self.toolsmenu.add_command(label = "Clear", command = self.cf)
        self.toolsmenu.add_command(label = "Find", command = self.fd)
        self.toolsmenu.add_command(label = "Syntax highlighting", command = self.sh)

        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Tools", menu = self.toolsmenu)

class Settings(object):

    def __init__(self, menubar, configFile):
        self.prefmenu = tkinter.Menu(menubar)

        self.prefmenu.add_command(label = "Settings", command = configFile)

        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Preferences", menu = self.prefmenu)
```

**syntaxhl.py**

```
import tkinter

def highlight(editor_space, searchfor, color):
    countVar = tkinter.StringVar()

    pos = "1.0"

    while True:
        pos = editor_space.search(searchfor, pos, tkinter.END, count = countVar)

        if not pos:
            break

        lastindex = "{} + {}c".format(pos, countVar.get())

        editor_space.tag_add("keyword", pos, lastindex)

        pos = lastindex

    editor_space.tag_configure("keyword", foreground = color)
```

**main.py**

```
try:
    import editor

except ImportError as e:
    import sys
    sys.exit("editor.py module missing.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edit = editor.Editor()
    edit.editor()
```

Comment: Neither `config` nor `syntaxHighligh` should be classes. Both look to me like a dictionary, the second one doesn't even try to hide it.

Answer (score 6):

1. As mentioned by @L3viathan, the `config` class should be a dictionary, not a static class of attributes. When you ever need to store values in such a way, that a grouped together under a category, use a dictionary, like this:

   ```
   CONFIG = {
       "config-attribute": "config-attribute-value"
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Secondly, your naming is off. Functions and variables should be in `lower_snake_case`, and classes should be in `PascalCase`. If the variable is constant, it should be in `UPPERCASE_SNAKE_CASE`.
3. I'm not sure if you're using Python 3.x, or Python 2.x, but if you're using Python 3.x, you don't need to explicitly inherit all your classes from `object`. You can just write them like this: `class MyClass:`. If you're using Python 2.x though, you should continue explicitly inheriting from `object`.
4. You're mixing use of single quotes, `''`, and double quotes, `""`. Preferably, you should choose one, and stick with that.
5. You need two blank spaces in between your top level functions/classes. This is part of [the official style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines).
6. Finally, add some comments. Your code is fairly readable, but it could definitely use some comments. First off, add some docstrings, `""" ... """`, to describe what your functions and classes do. To describe blocks of code, just use online comments, `# ...`.

Comment: You said: "you don't need to explicitly inherit all your classes from object", but what harm does it make?

Comment: @highlycorrosive There's no harm in doing it. It's just not necessary in Python 3.x. It also looks clearer as well.